# Watch app starts with big delay after calling HKHealthStore method startWatchApp(with:completion:)

Tags: ios, watchos, hkhealthstore

I'm working on workout iOS app with counterpart watchOS app, and I have issue with starting watch app from iOS using HKHealthStore method startWatchApp(with:completion:). Sometimes after calling startWatchApp method the watch app starts with huge delay - 1 min, sometimes 5 min, or even 20 min. Unfortunately I couldn’t find stable pattern of reproducing this issue.

I've created bug report in Apple bug reporter, but after checking it with all attached logs and [video](https://vimeo.com/258741500) they just said something like: "we didn't find anything in logs, sorry can't help more", and after that they didn't answer on my next message.

So, does anyone encountered that issue? Maybe someone know workaround? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Btw the documentation of that method says:

> After launching, the Watch app calls the WKExtensionDelegate object’s handle(_:) method and passes the provided workout configuration

but if the watch screen was off - “handle” method won’t be called after launching.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: Looks like Apple engineers improved that start functionality in latest versions, it still has some random delay but now works pretty good.